# Do my data follow normal distribution? and what does it mean if not? Can I have to peaks?

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption, histogram

I have to understand if my graphs follow the normal distribution but I don't know.
Can they have two peaks like two columns?
Are they normal or not?
what it means if they are not normal?
The aim is to analyze whether a certain body size of both genders fits the normal distribution. It's part of my uni paper but I've never did statistics I'm very much lost. I would say that just pelvic breadth for female follow a normal distribution because male have two columns and it's weird looking but idk. I don't know even what means if they don't follow normal distribution

[image]
[image]

Comment: please explain why you have to do this. is it homework , do you have to apply a statistical test etc

Comment: @seanv507 The aim is to analyze whether a certain body size of both genders fits the normal distribution. It's part of my uni paper but I've never did statistics I'm very much lost. I would say that just pelvic breadth for female follow a normal distribution because both male have two peaks and the other female it's weird looking but idk. I don't know even what means if they don't follow normal distribution

Comment: Some overlap with your other question to data https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/562283/if-i-have-body-measurements-weight-age-and-gender-of-500-people-what-is-the-be

Comment: please add this description to the main question, so others can find it easier.
 but my question is why do you have to "to understand if my graphs followt the normal distribution or not". so please answer that question ( in the main body of the question)

Comment: @seanv507 i don't know I never did statistic ever, my teacher asked if data had a not and to look at his paper for help (point 4, http://jse.amstat.org/v11n2/datasets.heinz.html ) so I tried to do the same but I can't read the graphs

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because it destroyed the plots in the post. When you edit please be careful not to destroy the graphs!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I re-added just the ones I didn't add in my final paper! I'm afraid my teacher will think I took the graphs from the web TT sorry

Answer (score 2):

First, please tell us why you need to do this (as an edit to the post). You have shown us four histograms, and at first sight they do look close to normal (with the maybe exception of first row, right, female pelvic, which might seem to have to many very low values for a normal).

But, histograms are not the best way to look for normality, qq-plots are often better.  For some examples see [R - QQPlot: how to see whether data are normally distributed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52293/r-qqplot-how-to-see-whether-data-are-normally-distributed), [How to interpret a QQ plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101274/how-to-interpret-a-qq-plot)

There are many similar posts on this site, some useful ones for you:

- [How to check if a data set can be modelled by a normal distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167163/how-to-check-if-a-data-set-can-be-modelled-by-a-normal-distribution)
- [is my data normally distributed or not](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399148/is-my-data-normally-distributed-or-not)
- [Normal Distribution or not?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204261/normal-distribution-or-not)
- [What is normality?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-is-normality)

Comment: The aim is to analyze whether a certain body size of both genders fits the normal distribution. I don't know what it means because I've never did statistic ever. Thank you! I'll do qqplot but for example the male distribution that has two peak, is it possibile? Don't normal distributions have one peak?

Comment: I do not understand how you can see two peaks there ...

Comment: Oh so the two columns aren't two peaks?

Comment: Two columns side-by-side just is a broader peak!

Comment: Oh thank you! so it's like two means near eachother